# Use intropection for __repr__ in Python

Tags: python, introspection

I have a custom class which could have 1 to n attributes.
How can I print my object to see attributes and their values?

I tried something like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(inspect.getmembers(self))
```

but I reach maximum recursion depth (for some obscure reasons to me).

Comment: Use `self.__dict__` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`vars([object])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) function which will return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.

```
car = Car()
vars(car)
# { 'color': 'red', 'manufacturer': 'Toyota' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference though, the reason why you get an infinite loop is the following:

1. `inspect.getmembers` is implemented as:

   ```
   def getmembers(object, predicate=None):
       results = []
       for key in dir(object):
           try:
               value = getattr(object, key)
           except AttributeError:
               continue
           if not predicate or predicate(value):
               results.append((key, value))
       results.sort()
       return results
   ```
2. Which boils down to:

   ```
   class Foo:
       def __repr__(self):
           try: v = getattr(self, "__repr__")
           except AttributeError:  pass
       return str(v) #str is a mandatory return type for __repr__
   ```

So basically because you have defined a `__repr__` method; it is an attribute of your class, and the `try-except` block will not `pass` over `getattr` statement. `getattr` will retrieve `__repr__` method and try to convert to `str` type, which is a mandatory return type of `__repr__`. `__repr__` gets called again to create the string representations of bound methods, which calls `inspect.getmembers` which calls `getattr` again and into an infinite loop. Thanks to  Jonas Wielicki for clearing this up.

(see [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28793687/2) if you need context for comments, I've cut it because it's wrong and off-topic)

Comment: I don't think so. A `getattr(self, "__repr__")` would return the associated function object, if there was one, not call it.

Comment: @martineau I'm not quite as sure as you are. It seems as if `__repr__` behaves more as a class attribute under the surface than as a function despite the fact it's a method. At one point in the execution (at printing or at `getattr`) `__repr__` has to be evaluated. See the edit above.

Comment: Upon conversion to str of the result from inspect.getmembers(), ``__repr__`` gets called to create the string representations of bound methods, which, as you note, require ``__repr__``. Thus the infinite recursion. No magic involved.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thanks for that, I've should have been more careful, I've edited the answer to match the correct answer.

Comment: Bound methods are objects of `<type 'instancemethod'>`. These objects have a built-in `__repr__` method, so `hasattr(getattr(b, "__repr__"), "__repr__")` --> `True`. When an attempt is made to print one of this bound method objects, _its_ `__repr__` method gets called, not the `__repr__` method of the class instance `b`. Apparently the built-in bound method's `__repr__` calls itself in the process of building the string it supposed to return—which is the real cause of the infinite recursion. Calling `getattr(self, "__repr__")` isn't calling the method, printing the value returned is doing it.